# How to use getch() (from curses library)?

Tags: c, ncurses

Consider this code:

```
if(initscr() == NULL) ERROR("Cannot start ncurses mode.\n");

    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    cbreak();

    int reply = getch(); 

    if(reply == 'y')
        printw("yes!\n");
    else if(reply == 'n')
        printw("no!\n");
    else
        printw("invalid answer!\n");

    refresh();

    endwin();
```

Independent of key that I type, the program closes without print any message.

Can someone explain the behavior of this program? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `printw()` to print one of three messages, then `refresh()` to cause the message to be displayed. So far, so good.

You then immediately call `endwin()`, which (depending on your termcap/terminfo settings) will likely clear the screen.

Chances are the message is actually displayed; it just doesn't stay on the screen long enough for you to read it.

Try adding a delay or another `getch()` call after the `refresh()` call.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert a sleep(5) in between your refresh() and your endwin(), you should see better results.  At least, I do.